# Flutter Gridview is not visible

Tags: flutter

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        home: new Scaffold(
          body: new Container(
          child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10.0,10.0, 10.0,10.0),
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                 timeslotsGrid()
         ],),),)));}

  Widget timeslotsGrid(){
    return Container(
child: GridView.count(
  primary: false,
  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
  crossAxisSpacing: 10.0,
  crossAxisCount: 2,
  children: <Widget>[
    const Text('He\'d have you all unravel at the'),
    const Text('Heed not the rabble'),
    const Text('Sound of screams but the'),
    const Text('Who scream'),
  ],)   ),}
```

I am implementing gridview in flutter.I tried by using the above code but the issue is the grid is not at all visible and the page is blank

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Change `Container` to `Expanded`

```
Widget timeSlotsGrid() {
    return Expanded(
      child: GridView.count(
        primary: false,
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
        crossAxisSpacing: 10.0,
        crossAxisCount: 2,
        children: <Widget>[
          const Text('He\'d have you all unravel at the'),
          const Text('Heed not the rabble'),
          const Text('Sound of screams but the'),
          const Text('Who scream'),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```